# xml parsing getting the element value null

Tags: android, xml, web-services, null, xml-parsing

I have create a webservice looks like :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <todoLists>
- <todoList>
  <productId>smthig</productId> 
  <siteCode>smthing</siteCode> 
  <subDeptId>smthing</subDeptId> 
  </todoList>
  </todoLists>
```

and  i am trying to parse it using DOM parser using below code , i am getting  nodeList.getLength() = 20 but not getting the value of the elements .it is showing null i have also tried the SAX parser but that is also giving null. Is there anything wrong with the webservice ?? please suggest.

```
public class XMLParsingDOMExample extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /** Create a new layout to display the view */
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(1);

        /** Create a new textview array to display the results */


        TextView category[];

        try {

            URL url = new URL(
            "http://xxxxxx:8080/webservicedemo/rest/todo");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("todoList");
            System.out.println("null 1");
            /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */


            category = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
            System.out.println("null 122 nodeList.getLength()" +nodeList.getLength());
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                category[i] = new TextView(this);
                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                category[i].setText("Name = "
                        + fstElmnt.getAttribute("siteCode"));


                layout.addView(category[i]);
                System.out.println("null 551");

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

        /** Set the layout view to display */
        setContentView(layout);

    }


    public class RSSAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Element rootElement;

        public RSSAdapter(Element rootElement) {
            this.rootElement = rootElement;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // get the count of children of the root element
            return 0;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // get the child identified by the position, 
            // this is the important part where you    
            // want to get the right child representing the RSS data that you want to get
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // implement your view here....
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your case `siteCode` is not Attributes its `Node of todoList`

**Solution**

```
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("siteCode").item(0).getChildNodes();
    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
    category[i].setText(nValue.getNodeValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop to this

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                NodeList nodes = nodeList.item(i).getChildNodes();
                category[i] = new TextView(this);
                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                // this will return node value of 2nd node  
                category[i].setText("Name = "
                        + fstElmnt.item(1).getNodeValue());


                layout.addView(category[i]);
                System.out.println("null 551");

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

iterate on nodelist and get the value of each child.

```
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("todoList");
    int length=nodeList.getLength();
    category = new TextView[length];

    for(int index=0;index<length;index++){
      Element element=(Element) nodeList.item(1ndex);
      NodeList childList=element.getElementsByTagName("siteCode");
      Element e=(Element) childList.item(0);
      Node n=e.getFirstChild();
      CharacterData data=(CharacterData)n;
      category[index].setText(data.getData());
     }//end for loop
```